# fan noise of dell inspirion after ubuntu 12.10 is installed alongside windows 7

Tags: fan, noise

How do i solve fan noise issue of dell inspirion 32 bit ubuntu 12.10 installed along side windows 7?

I tried many options indicated in the forum but nothing seem to work. when I try `touch /etc/fancontrol` it says `touch: cannot touch ‘/etc/fancontrol’: Permission denied`

Comment: Which graphic system/driver do you have? Often this is caused by suboptimal power management in the graphic card.

Comment: Intel® Ivybridge Mobile

Comment: Don't know. Try adding the result of the commands of `sudo lshw -short`, `sensors` and `top -b -n 1 | head -15` to the question, and see if anyone can find something... see how to format correctly the post by pressing "help" while editing, or look here: http://askubuntu.com/editing-help

Comment: Intel® Ivybridge Mobile

Answer (score 1):

Try the below command,

```
sudo touch /etc/fancontrol
```

Normal user can't be able to create a file inside `/etc` directory because it was owned by root.To create a file inside that, you need superuser do privilege or you must logged in as a root user.

Comment: jampel@jampel-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo touch /etc/fancontrol
[sudo] password for jampel: 
jampel@jampel-Inspiron-3521:~$ 
nothing happens!!!

Comment: yes, you successfully created `fancontrol` file inside `/etc` directory.Check it by running `ls -l /etc/fancontrol` command on terminal.

Comment: jampel@jampel-Inspiron-3521:~$ ls -l /etc/fancontrol-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 18 12:32 /etc/fancontrol
jampel@jampel-Inspiron-3521:~$ 
thanks Avinash! what next?

Comment: I posted the answer for the above problem only.Did you follow any link?

Comment: fan noise still persists

Comment: please explain your question briefly, so that we can be able to answer fully.You explained only the touch part, so i give the solution for only the part you explained on your question.

Comment: Go through all the questions in [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=fannoise+in+Ubuntu&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=dkgnU5aDKsu5rAe5gIHgBQ), it will surely help you.

Comment: jampel@jampel-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo apt-get install jupiter
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package jupiter
jampel@jampel-Inspiron-3521:~$

Comment: i run through this process again and again but i could not install jupiter ??any suggestion

Comment: jupiter is no more available.